# Watch YouTube videos faster than 2x speed?

Tags: youtube

The settings gear allows adjusting the speed of YouTube videos from 0.25x to 2x. What is the easiest possible way to watch YouTube videos at speeds faster than 2x?

Answer (score 2):

try this: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk)**

[image: enter image description here3]

also check these options:

[image: enter image description here2]
[image: enter image description here1]

Comment: Oh Mein Gott! I love this extension! Quality of life +4 and no gold & mithril spent! @user0 you are the best:)